# How to display any one of the images or first image from the folder in mvc application

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to display any one of the image or first image from the folder in my asp.net mvc application

now i am using like this

```
<img src="~/UserProfileImages/Images/100.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
```

but i want to display first image from folder without file name or extension... I have many images in folder.

Comment: you'll need a model property on your view which contains what you should set the source to `<img src="@Model.ImageSrc" class="img-responsive" alt="" />` and will need to populate the model property in the controller by analyzing the contents of teh directory, finding the first image and then setting the path of your model property to the desired image's path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class SomeController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var myModel = new ImageModel();
            var imagePaths = ReadPhotosFromDirectory();

            if(!imagePaths.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                //get the first file path from the directory
                myModel.ImageSrc = imagePaths[0];
            }

            return View(myModel);
        }

        //this method assumes all files in the directory are images.
        //you should check the file extensions as well to be safer
        private string[] ReadPhotosFromDirectory()
        {

            string[] fileLocations = Directory.GetFiles("\\your\\folder\\path").ToArray();
            return fileLocations;
        }
    }
```

then in your view reference the image source (view is Index.cshtml in this example):

```
@model MyApp.ImageModel

<img src="@Model.ImageSrc" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
```